# prism ConfigureContainer what for

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I m reading Prism library by microsoft. I just dont understand `ConfigureContainer()`.

The code in shell application like this:

```
 internal class JamSoftBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override IModuleEnumerator GetModuleEnumerator()
        {
            return new DirectoryLookupModuleEnumerator("Modules");
        }

        protected override void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IShellView, Shell>();

            base.ConfigureContainer();
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            ShellPresenter presenter = Container.Resolve<ShellPresenter>();
            IShellView view = presenter.View;
            view.ShowView();
            return view as DependencyObject;
        }
    }

    public interface IShellView
    {
        void ShowView();
    }

    public class ShellPresenter
    {
        public IShellView View { get; private set; }

        public ShellPresenter(IShellView view)
        {
           View = view;
        }
    }
```

I want to understand why I register IShellView,Shell in ConfigureContainer(). Whats going on behind sceens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`UnityBootstrapper`** provided by PRISM internally uses [**UnityContainer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx) to resolve dependency for your registered objects. You can configure your custom objects with it like you are doing in sample.

---

In your sample, you registered **`Shell`** with instance **`IShellView`**.

```
Container.RegisterType<IShellView, Shell>();
```

So whenever you ask container to get you object for IShellView, it will give you an instance of Shell object.

```
IShellView shellObject = Container.Resolve<IShellView>();
```

So, **`ConfigureContainer`** gives you support to register your objects with it's container.

---

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.practices.composite.unityextensions.unitybootstrapper.configurecontainer.aspx) link:

> Configures the IUnityContainer. May be overwritten in a derived class
>   to add specific type mappings required by the application.

Also, you can read more about it here - [Managing Dependencies Between Components Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I've registered to give you answer :). `ConfigureContainer` is just method from abstract class `UnityBootstrapper` where you can register all `Prism` services (`ModuleManager`, `RegionManager`, `EventAggregator`). You can make your custom `Bootstrapper` class, where you can manage your dependency. In your case, every time when you in your code ask for `IShellView`, you'll get instance of `Shell`.

I recommend you [this book](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42572). It's free.